# RemoveStoryBoard in codebehind crashes the application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm porting a style from XAML to code behind and I'm experiencing difficulties with the `RemoveStoryBoard`. The style is the following

```
<Style TargetType = "{x:Type telerik:GridViewCell}" x:Key="Style">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding = "{Binding IsChanged}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName = "Highlight" />
                <BeginStoryboard Name="Highlight">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Duration = "00:00:03" From="Red" FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the code behind is

```
private static Style CreateStyle(string color)
{
    var style = new Style(typeof(GridViewCell));

    var convertFromString = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color);
    if (convertFromString != null)
    {
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty,
            new SolidColorBrush((Color)convertFromString)));
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Warning("Unable to find a color for deal setting");
    }

    DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger
    {
        Value = true,
        Binding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("IsChanged")
        }
    };

    var storyboard = new BeginStoryboard();

    var sb = new Storyboard { Name = "Highlight" };
    storyboard.Storyboard = sb;

    var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation
    {
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)),
        From = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red,
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
    };

    PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath("(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, colorTargetPath);

    var removeStoryboard = new RemoveStoryboard { BeginStoryboardName = "Highlight" };
    //  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(removeStoryboard, colorTargetPath);

    sb.Children.Add(colorAnimation);

    trigger.EnterActions.Add(removeStoryboard);
    trigger.EnterActions.Add(storyboard);



    style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    return style;
}
```

If I comment the `RemoveStoryBoard` everything is fine but when I update another row even the previous blinks as well

If I use the `RemoveStoryBoard` I got an exception (and debugger /client freeze)
telling the "Highlight" cannot be found on the scope of "System.Windows.Style"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're adding both actions to the `EnterActions`.

Comment: in the XAML code it works doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the name "Highlight" with the `Style`. You also need to set the `Name` property of the `BeginStoryboard` object:

```
private static Style CreateStyle(string color)
{
    var style = new Style(typeof(GridViewCell));

    var convertFromString = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(color);
    if (convertFromString != null)
    {
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty,
            new SolidColorBrush((Color)convertFromString)));
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Warning("Unable to find a color for deal setting");
    }

    DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger
    {
        Value = true,
        Binding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("IsChanged")
        }
    };

    var storyboard = new BeginStoryboard() { Name = "Highlight" }; //<--

    var sb = new Storyboard { Name = "Highlight" };
    storyboard.Storyboard = sb;
    style.RegisterName("Highlight", storyboard); //<---

    var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation
    {
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)),
        From = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red,
        FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop,
    };

    PropertyPath colorTargetPath = new PropertyPath("(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)");

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, colorTargetPath);

    var removeStoryboard = new RemoveStoryboard { BeginStoryboardName = "Highlight" };
    //  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(removeStoryboard, colorTargetPath);

    sb.Children.Add(colorAnimation);

    trigger.EnterActions.Add(removeStoryboard);
    trigger.EnterActions.Add(storyboard);

    style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    return style;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't crash anymore but the previous still blink when updating the new

Comment: The previous? You apply the style to each individual cell, don't you?

Comment: Seems the problem of multiple row blink is due to another problem.... give you a feedback in a short